# I need to check and get record id list if some dates list is between start date and end date in one query mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

example
// dates list  '2022-2-24' ,'2022-2-27' , '2022-2-28','2022-3-01'
is between start_date column and end_date column
query

```
select id from leaves 
where '2022-2-24' ,'2022-2-27' , '2022-2-28','2022-3-01' between start_date  and end_date
```

Comment: Do you mean
`select id from leaves 
where  start_date < '2022-2-24'  and 2022-3-01' < end_date` ?

Comment: No,I need to check if any value of array list is between start_date column and end_date column

Comment: @AKOLAD This question is about `mysql`. Why an answer about couchDB sould help?

Comment: MySQL doesn’t support arrays. You’d need to use an OR statement for each date value you want to compare

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following style, however, your query gets longer.

```
SELECT id FROM leaves 
WHERE start_date >= '2022-02-24' AND end_date <= '2022-02-24' 
OR start_date >= '2022-02-27' AND end_date <= '2022-02-27'
OR start_date >= '2022-02-28' AND end_date <= '2022-02-28'
OR start_date >= '2022-03-01' AND end_date <= '2022-03-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

You haev to check all dates singularly

> ```
> CREATE TABLE leaves (id int,start_date date,end_date date )
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO leaves VALUES (1, '2022-02-02', '2022-03-02'),(2, '2022-01-02', '2022-02-02'),(3, '2022-01-02', '2022-03-10')
> ```

> ```
> select id from leaves 
> where '2022-2-24' between start_date  and end_date 
> OR '2022-2-27' between start_date  and end_date  
> OR '2022-2-28' between start_date  and end_date 
> OR '2022-3-01' between start_date  and end_date
> ```
>
> ```
> | id |
> | -: |
> |  1 |
> |  3 |
> ```

> ```
> select id from leaves 
> where '2022-2-24' between start_date  and end_date 
> UNION
> select id from leaves 
> where '2022-2-27' between start_date  and end_date  
> UNION
> select id from leaves 
> where '2022-2-28' between start_date  and end_date 
> UNION
> select id from leaves 
> where '2022-3-01' between start_date  and end_date
> ```
>
> ```
> | id |
> | -: |
> |  1 |
> |  3 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3768bd228814953947fc59343bba2d4f)*

Comment: OK this is work only if dates list is fixed but I need it dynamic and good performance if i have 30 dates on the list  , I need to send as array

Comment: mysql doesn't support array list, so you have o other choice for suc a query, the additional query i8 posted is faster on big taables and a combined KEY on start and end date. Another option is to have a table with te dates and then join it, but that neeeds even more programming